# If text box value is null then set dropdown list to null

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures

I have a page in C# on .NET that has a dropdown menu that is populated from a database the dropdown contains dialing codes for mobile phone numbers and defaults to 'United Kingdom (+44)'

However I also have a mobile number box where user can enter there mobile number. At the moment if the user saves without a mobile number (which is allowed) the dialing code will still get passed to the SP and ultimately be saved.

I want to find a way to stop this happening so if a user does not enter a mobile number the dialing code is set to null when entered in the database.

What is the best way to do this?

This is the C#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Dnuk.Core.DataAccess.UserOptIn;
using Dnuk.Core.Entities2;
using Dnuk.Core.DataAccess.CommonData;
using Dnuk.Core.DataAccess.Framework;



namespace Registration
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Step2.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Step2 : Basepage
    {

        protected int countryid = 240;

        protected AJAXFunctions m_AJAXFunctions;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            StringBuilder helptext = new StringBuilder();
            helptext.AppendLine("<span class='bluetext2'>Your password must:-</span>");
            helptext.AppendLine("");
            helptext.AppendLine("<ul class='bluetext2'>");
            helptext.AppendLine("   <li>Have at least 9 characters</li>");
            helptext.AppendLine("    <li>Contain mixed case letters</li>");
            helptext.AppendLine("    <li>Contain at least 1 number OR a special character</li>");
            helptext.AppendLine("</ul>");
            helptext.AppendLine("");
            helptext.AppendLine("<p class='bluetext2'>Allowed characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and these special characters: !@#$*^().,{}[]~-</p>");
            helptext.AppendLine("");
            helptext.AppendLine("<span class='bluetext2'>Not accepted:-</span>");
            helptext.AppendLine("");
            helptext.AppendLine("<ul class='bluetext2'>");
            helptext.AppendLine("    <li>the word 'password'</li>");
            helptext.AppendLine("    <li>using your username</li>");
            helptext.AppendLine("</ul>");

            Helpicon11.Text = helptext.ToString();

            m_AJAXFunctions = new AJAXFunctions();
            m_AJAXFunctions.Register();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlSpecialityList.Attributes.Add("onchange", "SpecialityList_Change();");
                lsbSubSpecialityUser.Style.Add("width", "200px");
                imbNext.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Validation();");
                ddlProfessionalStatusList.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CheckProfStatusSeniority();");
                ddlSeniorityList.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CheckProfStatusSeniority();");
                ddlCountry.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ChangeCountry();");
                FillData();
                FillUserData();
            }
        }


        protected void ddlSeniorityList_Fill()
        {
            ddlSeniorityList.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlSeniorityList.DataValueField = "seniorityid";

            using (DBAccess db = new DBAccess())
            {
                ddlSeniorityList.DataSource = (db.GetSpecialitySeniorityList(countryid)).Tables[0];
            }

            ddlSeniorityList.DataBind();
            ddlSeniorityList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("please select", "0"));
        }


        protected void ddlSpecialityList_Fill()
        {
            ddlSpecialityList.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlSpecialityList.DataValueField = "specialityid";

            using (DBAccess db = new DBAccess())
            {
                ddlSpecialityList.DataSource = (db.GetSpecialitySeniorityList(countryid)).Tables[1];
            }

            ddlSpecialityList.DataBind();
            ddlSpecialityList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("please select", "0"));
        }


        protected void ddlProfessionalStatusList_Fill()
        {
            ddlProfessionalStatusList.DataTextField = "title";
            ddlProfessionalStatusList.DataValueField = "ProfStatusId";

            using (DBAccess db = new DBAccess())
            {
                ddlProfessionalStatusList.DataSource = db.GetProfessionalStatusList();
            }

            ddlProfessionalStatusList.DataBind();
        }


        protected void ddlCountry_Fill()
        {
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "countryname";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "countryid";

            using (DBAccess db = new DBAccess())
            {
                ddlCountry.DataSource = db.GetCountryList();
            }

            ddlCountry.DataBind();
            ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("please select", "0"));
        }


        protected void cLVOptins_Fill()
        {
            UserOptInDAO userOptInDAO = new UserOptInDAO();
            cLVOptins.DataSource = userOptInDAO.GetRegistrationOptInList();
            cLVOptins.DataBind();
        }


        private void FillData()
        {
            ddlSeniorityList_Fill();
            ddlSpecialityList_Fill();
            ddlProfessionalStatusList_Fill();
            ddlCountry_Fill();
            cLVOptins_Fill();
        }


        protected void FillUserData()
        {
            if (Session["Registration_RegInfo"] != null)
            {
                RegInfo ri = (RegInfo)Session["Registration_RegInfo"];

                if (ddlSeniorityList.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(ri.SeniorityID)) != null)
                    ddlSeniorityList.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ri.SeniorityID);
                if (ddlSpecialityList.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(ri.SpecialityID)) != null)
                    ddlSpecialityList.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ri.SpecialityID);
                ddlProfessionalStatusList.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ri.ProfessionalStatusID);
                hdnPCT_NHSID.Value = Convert.ToString(ri.PCT_NHSID);
                hdnGP_TrustID.Value = Convert.ToString(ri.GP_TrustID);

                using (DBAccess helper = new DBAccess())
                {
                    if (ri.HPOTypeIDs != null)
                    {
                        hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value = Convert.ToString(ri.HPOTypeIDs);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //the default HPO types should be "All"
                        DataTable dt = helper.GetHPOTypes();
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value += Convert.ToString(dr["OrgnTypeID"]) + ",";
                        }
                        if (hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value.Length > 0)
                            hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value = hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value.Substring(0, hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value.Length-1);

                    }
                    this.lblSelectedOrgTypes.Text = helper.GetHPOTypeNames(hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value);
                }

                ddlDialingCode.Text = ri.DialingCodeText;
                txbPostcode.Text = ri.Postcode;
                txbLocality.Text = ri.Locality;
                txbAddress1.Text = ri.Address1;
                txbAddress2.Text = ri.Address2;
                txbCity.Text = ri.City;
                txbCounty.Text = ri.County;
                if (ri.CountryID != 0)
                    ddlCountry.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ri.CountryID);
                else
                    ddlCountry.SelectedValue = "240";

                txt_username.Value = ri.Username;

                txbAltEMail.Text = ri.AltEMail;
                if (ri.DialingCodeID != 0)
                    ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(ri.DialingCode);
                else
                    ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue = "240";

                txbPhoneNumber.Text = ri.PhoneNumber;
                if (ri.SubSpecialityIDs != null)
                    SubSpecialityIDs = ri.SubSpecialityIDs; 
                txbSecWord1.Text = ri.SecWord1;
                txbSecWord2.Text = ri.SecWord2;


                if (ri.OptIns != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32, bool> entry in ri.OptIns)
                    {
                        foreach (ListViewItem item in cLVOptins.Items)
                        {
                            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cCbOptIn");
                            Int32 optInId = Convert.ToInt32(chkBox.InputAttributes["optId"]);

                            if (optInId == entry.Key)
                            {
                                chkBox.Checked = entry.Value;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        private void PutRegInfo()
        {
            if (Session["Registration_RegInfo"] != null)
            {
                RegInfo ri = (RegInfo)Session["Registration_RegInfo"];

                ri.SeniorityID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSeniorityList.SelectedValue);
                ri.SpecialityID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSpecialityList.SelectedValue);
                ri.SubSpecialityIDs = SubSpecialityIDs;
                ri.PCT_NHSID = Convert.ToInt32(hdnPCT_NHSID.Value);
                ri.GP_TrustID = Convert.ToInt32(hdnGP_TrustID.Value);
                ri.HPOTypeIDs = Convert.ToString(hdnHPOTypeIDs.Value);
                ri.ProfessionalStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProfessionalStatusList.SelectedValue);
                ri.Postcode = txbPostcode.Text.Trim();
                ri.Locality = txbLocality.Text.Trim();
                ri.Address1 = txbAddress1.Text.Trim();
                ri.Address2 = txbAddress2.Text.Trim();
                ri.City = txbCity.Text.Trim();
                ri.County = txbCounty.Text.Trim();
                ri.CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);

                ri.Username = txt_username.Value.Trim();
                ri.Password = txt_newpassw.Value.Trim();

                ri.AltEMail = txbAltEMail.Text.Trim();
                ri.PhoneNumber = txbPhoneNumber.Text.Trim();
                ri.DialingCodeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue);
                ri.DialingCode = ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue;
                ri.DialingCodeText = ddlDialingCode.SelectedItem.Text;
                ri.SecWord1 = txbSecWord1.Text.Trim();
                ri.SecWord2 = txbSecWord2.Text.Trim();

                // string fields
                ri.Seniority = ddlSeniorityList.SelectedItem.Text;
                ri.Speciality = ddlSpecialityList.SelectedItem.Text;
                ri.SubSpecialities = SubSpecialities;
                ri.PCT_NHS = hdnPCT_NHS.Value;
                ri.GP_Trust = hdnGP_Trust.Value;
                ri.ProfessionalStatus = ddlProfessionalStatusList.SelectedItem.Text;
                ri.Country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text;


                if (ri.OptIns == null)
                    ri.OptIns = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

                ri.OptIns.Clear();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in cLVOptins.Items)
                {
                    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cCbOptIn");
                    Int32 optInId = Convert.ToInt32(chkBox.InputAttributes["optId"]);

                    ri.OptIns.Add(optInId, chkBox.Checked);
                }                

                Session.Add("Registration_RegInfo", ri);
            }
        }


        protected void imbNext_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {


            // check passwords
            using (DBAccess da = new DBAccess())
            {
                UP_Validation_Username.Username upv_uname = new UP_Validation_Username.Username();
                UP_Validation_Password.Password upv_pass = new UP_Validation_Password.Password();

                string codes = string.Empty;
                string codes1 = string.Empty;
                string codes2 = string.Empty;

                System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader _configReader = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
                string skey = _configReader.GetValue("UP_SecurityKey", typeof(string)).ToString();

                codes1 = upv_pass.Password_Validation_Lite(skey, txt_username.Value, txt_newpassw.Value, txt_newpassw1.Value);
                codes2 = upv_uname.Username_Validation(skey, txt_username.Value, 0);

                if (codes1 == "1" && codes2 == "1")
                {
                    codes = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    codes = codes1 + "," + codes2;
                    char[] comma = new char[] { ',' };
                    codes = codes.TrimEnd(comma);
                    codes = codes.TrimStart(comma);
                }

                if (codes != "1")
                {
                    err_username.InnerHtml = "";
                    err_newpassw.InnerHtml = "";
                    err_newpassw1.InnerHtml = "";

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds = upv_pass.GetErrorMessages(skey, codes);

                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt = ds.Tables[0];

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            switch (dr["type"].ToString())
                            {
                                case "username":
                                    err_username.InnerHtml = err_username.InnerHtml + dr["message"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                                    break;
                                case "newpassword":
                                    err_newpassw.InnerHtml = err_newpassw.InnerHtml + dr["message"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                                    break;
                                case "newpassword1":
                                    err_newpassw1.InnerHtml = err_newpassw1.InnerHtml + dr["message"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PutRegInfo();
                    if (Request.QueryString["redirecttoansaedu"] != null)
                        Response.Redirect("Step3.aspx?redirecttoansaedu=1", true);
                    else Response.Redirect("Step3.aspx", true);
                }

            }

        }


        protected int[] SubSpecialityIDs
        {
            get
            {
                const char DELIMITER = '\x0001';

                string[] sArray;
                if (hdnSubSpecialityIDs.Value == "")
                    sArray = new string[0];
                else
                    sArray = hdnSubSpecialityIDs.Value.Split(DELIMITER);

                return ConvertArray_ToInt(sArray);
            }
            set
            {
                const char DELIMITER = '\x0001';

                hdnSubSpecialityIDs.Value = String.Join(Convert.ToString(DELIMITER), ConvertArray_ToString(value));
            }
        }


        protected string[] SubSpecialities
        {
            get
            {
                const char DELIMITER = '\x0001';
                if (hdnSubSpecialityIDs.Value == "")
                    return new string[0];
                else
                    return hdnSubSpecialities.Value.Split(DELIMITER);
            }
            set
            {
                const char DELIMITER = '\x0001';

                hdnSubSpecialities.Value = String.Join(Convert.ToString(DELIMITER), value);
            }
        }


        protected int[] ConvertArray_ToInt(object[] array)
        {
            int[] result = new int[array.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);

            return result;
        }


        protected string[] ConvertArray_ToString(int[] array)
        {
            string[] result = new string[array.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                result[i] = Convert.ToString(array[i]);

            return result;
        }


        protected void cLVOptins_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
            {
                UserOptIn optIn = (UserOptIn)e.Item.DataItem; 

                //Hide the help icon when there is no helptext
                if (optIn.HelpText == string.Empty)
                {
                    Registration.Controls.HelpIcon helpIcon = (Registration.Controls.HelpIcon)e.Item.FindControl("cHelpIconOptIn");
                    helpIcon.Visible = false;
                }

                //Remove indent where there is no parent
                if (optIn.ParentId == 0)
                {
                    Label cLblIndent = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("cLblIndent");
                    cLblIndent.Visible = false;
                }

                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cCbOptIn");
                chkBox.Checked = optIn.Default;
                chkBox.InputAttributes.Add("optId", optIn.Id.ToString());

                //bit of a hack
                if (optIn.Description.IndexOf("Market Research invitations") > -1)
                {
                    chkBox.Text = chkBox.Text + "<div class=\"greytext1 optInIndent\" optparentid=\"1\">You will receive invitations through the Doctors.net.uk website or by e-mail. Some surveys are also conducted by telephone. To ensure you are invited to these surveys as well, please indicate this below.</div>";
                }

            }
        }

        protected void DialingCodeDropDown_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommonDataSource cds = new CommonDataSource();
            cds.SQLExecutorSource = new SQLHelperExecutorSource();
            List<RefCountry> countries = cds.RefCountries();
            List<ListItem> adjustedCountriesList = new List<ListItem>();    


            foreach (RefCountry country in countries)
            {
                if (country.DiallingCode.Trim() == "")
                    continue;

                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Value = country.CountryID.ToString();
                item.Text = String.Format("{0} (+{1})", country.CountryName, country.DiallingCode.Trim());
                adjustedCountriesList.Add(item);               
            }


            ddlDialingCode.DataSource = adjustedCountriesList;            
            ddlDialingCode.DataBind();  


        }

        #region Web Form Designer generated code
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
            //
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {    

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the mobilephone number text box defined in the HTML

```
                    <tr>                                
                        <td align="right" valign="middle" class="bluetext2b">Mobile phone number</td>
                        <td><uc:HelpIcon id="Helpicon14" runat="server" Title="Mobile phone number" Text="Add your mobile number including the '0' and with no spaces. If you are not resident in the UK, please ensure you change the international dialling code to the appropriate country. Please note: Your mobile number will not be shared with a third party. If you opt in to take part in Market Research telephone surveys, this field will be mandatory. ."></uc:HelpIcon>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" ID="ddlDialingCode" Runat="server" CssClass="myinput1" OnInit="DialingCodeDropDown_Init"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txbPhoneNumber" Runat="server" onkeypress="return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the mobile number field is empty or not. If it is empty stop the execution of the Save operation and return some message. You can check it like that:

In the `DialingCodeDropDown_Init` you can add a default ListItem with Value = 0 and Text = "" ( if you can, because sometimes the client must not have this option to select). Then in `PutRegInfo` method on the line containing : `ri.PhoneNumber = txbPhoneNumber.Text.Trim();` add the following code:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txbPhoneNumber.Text))
{
    ri.DialingCodeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue);
    ri.DialingCode = ddlDialingCode.SelectedValue;
    ri.DialingCodeText = ddlDialingCode.SelectedItem.Text;
}
else
{
    ri.DialingCodeID = 0;
    ri.DialingCode = "0";
    ri.DialingCodeText = "";
}
```

Comment: This will not work as far as I can see because there shouldn't be an error as the user is allowed to not enter a mobile number, but if the user does choose to do this the selected value should be null from the dropdown

Comment: Ok, then if the mobilePhone is empty don't show error message, just select the 0 element from the DropDown (if there is such) or put string.Empty in the SQL param for it. If you want more direct help add your code in the question.

Comment: Still not working I have added a new row in the database that has 0 as an ID and '' as the text. I added in the IF statement supplied directly below ri.PhoneNumber = txbPhoneNumber.Text.Trim(); but it still saves a value of 240

Comment: Can you explain then what should be the behavior if the number is empty? What should be saved for the dialing code in the database?

Comment: If the user does not enter any information in the mobile number text box the dialingcode should be saved as 0 in the database or null, only when the user has a mobile number entered should the selected  dialingcode be saved. The dialingcode dropdown however has to default to UK which has an ID of 240 when the page is loaded.

Comment: The code in the else statement iny answer should overwrite the default UK value to 0. Is it not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59089/discussion-between-legend1989-and-atanas-desev).